# Getting size of array in XTemplate

Tags: gxt

First of all, I'm working with GXT 2.2.5 and GWT 2.3.

I have a ListView that displays the items generated by a user. I want it to display the items already entered, or a single row that says "No Items Attached" if the store is empty.

I figure I could use the "tpl if" tag in the template, but how can I detemine the size of the store for comparison?

In other words, what value do I use for "size" in the following?

```
<tpl if="size == 0">
  <p>No Items attached</p>
</tpl>
<tpl if="size > 0">
  <tpl for =".">
    ...
  </tpl>
</tpl>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GXT 2 XTemplates are based on JavaScript, so instead of keying off of `size`, use `length`, the name of the property that holds the size of a JavaScript array. In GXT 3, XTemplates were rewritten to work with any Java object, so expect the size method like you've written here.

Modified template from http://www.sencha.com/examples-2/#listview :

```
private native String getTemplate() /*-{
  return ['<tpl if="length == 0">',
              'nothing to show',
          '</tpl>',
          '<tpl if="length != 0">',
              '<tpl for=".">',
                  '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{name}">',
                      '<div class="thumb"><img src="{path}" title="{name}"></div>',
                      '<span class="x-editable">{shortName}</span>',
                  '</div>',
              '</tpl>',
              '<div class="x-clear"></div>',
          '</tpl>'
   ].join("");
 }-*/;
```

Comment: I tried this, but the problem I'm having is that the ListView is not updating properly. The code starts with an empty store, so it displays the empty line correctly. I add a record, and it changes accordingly. But when I delete the record, the ListView does not switch back to the emptry version.

Comment: The problem is that when an item is removed from the store, the listview tries to be clever and doesn't re-run the entire template - it just slices out the removed element. Consider adding a remove event listener to the store and if the item count == 0, then call store.clear() to get it re-run?